# I need help with a proof regarding Fibonacci sequence.

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have constructed a formula for the terms of the Fibonacci sequence for positive integer $n$. It is:
$$
\frac{a^{n}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^n}{1+a^2} 
$$
where $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, and $b=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
I tested few terms out and it does represent the Fib. sequence well, but I want to have a concrete mathematical proof of it as well. Which I planned to do by referring to a fact that the division of two neighboring Fib. terms approaches the Golden ratio, $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=a$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. Therefore I wanted to prove my formula for Fib. terms by showing that

$$
\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^{n+1}}{1+a^2}}{\frac{a^{n}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^n}{1+a^2}}=a.
$$
By taking advantage of the fact that $a=-b^{-1}$ and $b=-a^{-1}$ I arrived to the following
$$
\frac{\frac{a^2a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{1+a^2}}{\frac{a^2a^n+b^n}{1+a^2}}=\frac{a^2a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^2a^n+b^n}
$$
And from here since $b=-a^{-1}$, $b^{n+1}=\frac{-1}{a^{n+1}}$ and $b^{n}=\frac{-1}{a^{n}}$. When we substitute these values back we get:
$$
\frac{a^{n+3}+\frac{-1}{a^{n+1}}}{a^{n+2}+\frac{-1}{a^{n}}}=\frac{\frac{a^{2n+4}-1}{a^{n+1}}}{\frac{a^{2n+3}-1}{a^{n}}}=\frac{a^{2n+4}-1}{a(a^{2n+3}-1)}
$$
And at this moment I was not sure how to advance. Any help in proving this fraction is equal to $a$ will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why should the ratio of two neighboring Fibonacci numbers be the golden ratio? After all, the Fibonacci numbers are integers and the golden ratio is irrational...

Comment: @kandb Take for example two neighboring terms of the Fibonacci sequence, 377 and 233. 377/233=1.61802. Golden ratio = 1.61803. Ratio between neighboring terms being golden ratio is simply the characteristic of the Fibonacci sequence as far as I know.

Comment: The ratio between pairs of successive Fibonacci numbers converges to the golden ratio as $n\to\infty$, but it is *never* equal to the golden ratio.

Comment: @kandb Correct. Do you think it is impossible to mathematically prove   that my formula behaves the same as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

Comment: It is definitely possible to prove it, but you start by writing 

$$
\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^{n+1}}{1+a^2}}{\frac{a^{n}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^n}{1+a^2}}=a.
$$

which is never true. On the other hand, 

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^{n+1}}{1+a^2}}{\frac{a^{n}}{1+b^2}+\frac{b^n}{1+a^2}}=a
$$

*is* true.

Comment: @kandb Could you then perhaps help me construct the proof more accurately. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142810/discussion-between-kandb-and-mihailo).

Comment: $-1<b<1$ so $b^n\rightarrow 0$. To prove your original formula, you can derive it from the recurrence relation using the standard solution techniques for such relations - find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which are $a$ and $b$, and then find the two coefficients of $a^n$ and $b^n$ by solving for two specific values of $n$.

Comment: Call $A_n$ the number defined by your formula. Why don't you just prove that $A_{n+2}=A_{n}+A_{n+1}$? Btw, such formulae for recurrence sequences are well-known and established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kandb noted in the comments, the correct mathematical statement should say that the *limit* equals to the golden ratio, not that any adjacent terms divide to the golden ratio. That is, you are saying that you want to prove

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{a^{n + 1}}{1 + b^2} + \frac{b^{n + 1}}{1 + a^2}}{\frac{a^n}{1 + b^2} + \frac{b^n}{1 + a^2}} = a
$$

(Bravo for typing it correctly!) Actually, you have come really close already. In your last simplifying line, you wrote

$$
(LHS = ) \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{n+3}+\frac{-1}{a^{n+1}}}{a^{n+2}+\frac{-1}{a^{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{a^{2n+4}-1}{a^{n+1}}}{\frac{a^{2n+3}-1}{a^{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{2n+4}-1}{a(a^{2n+3}-1)}
$$

However, there is an arithmetic mistake:

$$
(LHS = ) \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{n+3}+\frac{-1}{a^{n+1}}}{a^{n+2}+\frac{-1}{a^{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a^{2n+4}-1)/a^{n+1}}{(a^{2n+{\color{red}2}}-1) / a^{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{2n+4}-1}{a(a^{2n+{\color{red}2}}-1)}
$$

Fixing this mistake, the problem becomes easy. It is not hard to show that the constants $- 1$ don't matter, i.e.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^{2n + 4} - 1}{a(a^{2n + 2} - 1)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^{2n + 4}}{a(a^{2n + 2})} = a
$$

Where the right hand side is exactly what you want to prove! This "removing constants" can be justified by various ways e.g. the squeeze theorem. I can elaborate on this if you need it :)

---

Just for your interest (and @kandb's), I will show that all second-order linear recurrences with positive coefficients will grow. Specifically, consider a recurrence $f(n) = af(n - 1) + bf(n - 2)$ and some initial values $f(1) = x$ and $f(2) = y$ that won't matter. Notice(!) that we can write this as a matrix equation:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} f(n) \\ f(n - 1) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f(n - 1) \\ f(n - 2) \end{pmatrix}
$$

By some simple induction, we see that

$$
\begin{pmatrix} f(n) \\ f(n - 1) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{n - 2} \begin{pmatrix} f(2) \\ f(1) \end{pmatrix} = A^{n - 2}\vec{v}
$$

Now this is just a standard linear algebra problem. If you work out all the details, diagonalising the matrix and such, you will see that you get $f(n) = A\lambda_1^n + B\lambda_2^n$ for some unspecified constants $A, B$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are roots of the equation $\lambda^2 = a\lambda + b$. Look - this looks exactly like our recurrence definition $f(n) = af(n - 1) + bf(n - 2)$! Solving this equation for $a = b = 1$ also yields $\lambda = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, which appears in Pinet's formula that you wrote. This can be shown via induction, or Cayley-Hamilton, or whatever. Also, this equation $\lambda^2 = a\lambda + b$ is called the *characteristics* polynomial of the recurrence, which generalises naturally to higher order recurrence.

Finally, to link this back to your original question of finding the limit of the ratio of adjacent terms, we look at

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A\lambda_1^{n + 1} + B\lambda_2^{n + 1}}{A\lambda_1^n + B\lambda_2^n}
$$

I forgot about the details exactly, but for "nice" values of $\lambda$'s like $\max(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) > 1$ and $\min(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) > -1$, it is easy to show that the limit is $\max(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$. Intuitively it makes sense: In the long run, the expression $A\lambda_1^n + B\lambda_2^n$ is dominated by whichever $\lambda$ is larger, modulo some negative annoyance.

Here's some extra questions to think about. You can also construct a sequence with the properties below and look at the values numerically :)

- What if $\lambda_1 < -1$? Then $\lambda_1^n$ will flip signs every term, such as $1, -2, 4, -8, 16, -32$. What impact does that have on the recurrence values?
- What if $\lambda$ are complex numbers? This happens for $\lambda^2 = 2\lambda - 2$ i.e. $f(n) = 2f(n - 1) - 2f(n - 2)$, for example.

Comment: Cool answer! For my own curiosity, is the Fibonacci sequence the only sequence for which the ratio of the successive terms tends to the golden ratio?

Comment: @kandb I mean my answer is just fixing his mistake :) Anyways, the answer is quite obviously no, taking the geometric sequence for example. For a more interesting sequence, consider the second-order linear homogeneous recurrence $f(n)=af(n-1)+bf(n-2)$, where $a,b>1$ for simplicity sake. Then it can be checked that $f(n)$ always grow exponentially. Actually, I will add this discussion to the answer, since there's a character limit hahahaha

Comment: That was what I was thinking, too :) Then I'm wondering if his question is asking how to prove that the sequence he has constructed is the Fibonacci sequence or just that the ratio of the successive terms tends to the golden ratio

Comment: @kandb I updated with some information. Kind of got distracted at the end but hope you and OP finds it interesting.

Comment: thanks for the explanation--it IS interesting! :)

Comment: @GarethMa Thank you so much!

Comment: @GarethMa Could you actually just briefly elaborate on the justification behind the removal of the constants? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: @Mihailo I will use a simpler example, with $f(n) = \frac{2^{n + 1} - 3}{2^n - 1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n-n}$. We simply squeeze it with two trivial bounds. Note that $\frac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n}<\frac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n-1}<\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n-1}$. Then, the limit of the leftmost expression is $2$ since $\frac{3}{2^n}$ clearly has limit $0$. For the rightmost expression, just divide it out and you get $\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n-1}=2+\frac{2}{2^n-1}$, and the result follows again.

Answer (score 0):

If the proposed formula for the Fibonacci numbers is correct, then it must be equivalent to the Binet formula, to wit,

$$
F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}
$$

where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $\psi=1-\varphi=-1/\varphi$

Now let's look a the proposed equation,

$$
f_n=\frac{\varphi^n}{1+\psi^2}+\frac{\psi^n}{1+\varphi^2}
$$

Substituting $1+\varphi^2=\varphi(\varphi-\psi)=-(\varphi-\psi)/\psi$ and $1+\psi^2=(\varphi-\psi)/\varphi$, we can readliy show that

$$
f_n=\frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\varphi-\psi}
$$

So the correct answer is that proposed formula gives correct Fibonacci numbers, but *not* in the usual convention for the exponent $n$. You can see that the original formula is incorrect for $n=0$.

I have verified these results numerically.